# Mongoose findOne() returns null for both error and expected value. How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a simple API and I have a user registration end point that persists user details to mongodb. When I try to look up a specific user using the findOne(), I get null for both error and the expected object. However if I lookup the users using find() I get all users in the database.

I have looked into the mongoose documentation and I don't see anything I might be doing wrong. Is this an issue with mongoose or what? Below is the simple login endpoint

```
const express = require('express');
const Stylist = require('../models/Stylist');

const router = express.Router();

// login route
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // look up user in the database
    Stylist.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    .then((records) => {
        console.log(records)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

});

// export the router
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I ran your login route code but i didn't find any error, it's sending me the requested user from db. Have you used body parser? and post exact error what you've found in the code

Comment: I am also facing same issue . Could someone help us?

Comment: This worked for me: db.collection.findOne({''emai''l:req.body.email})
    .then((records) => {
        console.log(records)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })